# I am using navbar-static-top + navbar-fixed-bottom and I want to fill the container in between to 100% height. How?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using navbar-static-top + navbar-fixed-bottom and I want to fill the container in between to 100% height. How?

It has only 3 rows, first and third row are the navbars. Center row is a container-fluid with row-fluid.

I tried EVERYTHING even sticky footer trick, but just cant make it fill up properly without having a scrollbar, because it inherit 100% excluding the navbars.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed this.

I just had to change both NavBars to navbar-fixed-top and navbar-fixed-bottom.

Then the middle row height to 100% padding-top: 50px, padding-bottom: 50px.